# Android relative layout center horizontally with another view

Tags: android, xml, layout, view, center

I want to make some layout like this.

[image]
Those views represents:

- A is a message box.
- B is a Profile picture
- C is a description that should be on the right side of A & Center vertically with B

Some conditions are:
 - A should be above B & Center horizontally with B
 - Width of A is always greater than B
 - Height of C is always smaller than B
 - There shouldn't be a gap between B and C

If I put all three objects in a single container, I couldn't find a way to align A and B center horizontally. (`layout_below` puts B under A but aligned left)

I also tried to make a container including A and B, but if so, I cannot put C right after B (It causes a gap between B and C because A's width is greater than B).

Is there any way I can archive this only with XML layouts?

Comment: Have A and B different sizes (width)?

Comment: A is always larger than B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally think that it is impossible to reach what you want without an additional code from you.

I could reach what you want by setting `android:layout_marginLeft` in View B. To keep the view centered with A, you must always set the margin by following formula:

```
android:layout_marginLeft = ( (width_from_A / 4) + (width_from_B / 2) )
```

In my example below, `width_from_A == 200dp` and `width_from_B == 50dp`

So,

```
android:layout_marginLeft = ( (200 / 4) + (50 / 2) )
android:layout_marginLeft = ( 50 + 25 )
android:layout_marginLeft = 75dp
```

**Java**

If your view does not always have same width, you can dynamically set the margins via Java code. This should work because in your activity, right before display the Layout to the user, you can get width from A and width from B and manually set the LeftMarging for B.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    int widthA = findViewById(R.id.viewA).getLayoutParams().width;
    int widthB = findViewById(R.id.viewB).getLayoutParams().width;

    // THIS LINE JUST WORK FOR API>17
    ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)findViewById(R.id.viewB).getLayoutParams()).setMarginStart(widthA/4 + widthB/2);

    //FOR ANY API
    ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)findViewById(R.id.viewB).getLayoutParams()).setMargins(widthA/4 + widthB/2,0,0,0);

    super.onResume();
}
```

**Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewA"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="A"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/viewA">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewB"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="B"
            android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewC"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="C"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/viewB"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I also ended up implemented mine in this same way except I used `A.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);` and `layoutParams.leftMargin = A.getMeasuredWidth() / 2 + B.getMeasuredWidth() / 2`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this layout might suit your needs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/view_1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <View
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/view_1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/view_1"
        android:layout_below="@id/view_1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <View
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/view_2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/view_2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view_2"
        android:gravity="center">

        <View
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It conforms you needs:

> A: A message box that should be above B & Center horizontally with B
>
> B: Profile picture
>
> C: Description that should be on the right side of A & Center vertically with B

However is based on some assumtions:

1. *A* width is greater than than *B* width.
2. *B* height is greater than than *C* height

Comment: I tried this, but C need to be right after A. In this layout, there's a gap between A and C dependent on A's width. I'll edit my question to clarify this. But thanks for your answer.